# C# Can't Add to List of Objects (cannot convert date type)

Tags: c#, list

I'm have 3 "BOMrow", which are added to "itemBOMList". Each "BOMrow" is a class, ParentChildPair.
Then do groupby to the "itemBOMList", having "result".
Finally I want to add the "result" to the master list, "BOMList".
However, a error shows "**cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Child, bool IsReferencePart, string Parent, int Quantity>>' to 'addToList.ParentChildPair'**"

I tried to add .Cast<ParentChildPair>() before ToList(), but this does not work either, showing "**cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<addToList.ParentChildPair>' to 'addToList.ParentChildPair'**". Please help.

```
class ParentChildPair
    {
        public string Parent { get; set; }
        public string Child { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool IsReferencePart { get; set; }
    }


    

 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ParentChildPair> itemBOMList;
        itemBOMList = new List<ParentChildPair>();

        List<ParentChildPair> BOMList;
        BOMList = new List<ParentChildPair>();

        List<ParentChildPair> newresult;

        //List<ParentChildPair> convertedResult;
        //convertedResult = new List<ParentChildPair>();

        ParentChildPair BOMrow = new ParentChildPair();

        BOMrow.Parent = "parent1";
        BOMrow.Child = "child1";
        BOMrow.Quantity = 1;
        BOMrow.IsReferencePart = false;
        itemBOMList.Add(BOMrow);

        BOMrow = new ParentChildPair();
        //BOMrow = null;

        BOMrow.Parent = "parent1";
        BOMrow.Child = "child2";
        BOMrow.Quantity = 1;
        BOMrow.IsReferencePart = false;
        itemBOMList.Add(BOMrow);

        BOMrow = new ParentChildPair();

        BOMrow.Parent = "parent1";
        BOMrow.Child = "child2";
        BOMrow.Quantity = 2;
        BOMrow.IsReferencePart = false;
        itemBOMList.Add(BOMrow);

        var result = itemBOMList.GroupBy(d => d.Child)
.Select(
    g => new
    {
        Child = g.Key,
        IsReferencePart = g.First().IsReferencePart,
        Parent = g.First().Parent,
        Quantity = g.Sum(s => s.Quantity)
    }).ToList();

        BOMList.Add(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: `g => new` -> `g => new ParentChildPair`. Also, you can't add a list to a list with `.Add`, you need to use `.AddRange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linq query is returning IEnumerable of anonymous objects. You need to make an instance of `ParentChildPair`. Then you can add it to list, but you need use `AddRange` method because result of your query will be `IEnumerable`.

```
var result = itemBOMList.GroupBy(d => d.Child)
.Select(
    g => new ParentChildPair
    {
        Child = g.Key,
        IsReferencePart = g.First().IsReferencePart,
        Parent = g.First().Parent,
        Quantity = g.Sum(s => s.Quantity)
    }).ToList();

    BOMList.AddRange(result);
```